# Beginning iPhone/iPad Development Question

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4

I am trying to learn how to write programs for the iPhone/iPad the only problem I have run into is everything I have read, and every video tutorial refers to Xcode 3, which doesn't help me. I just started with this, and have never used xCode before this, so I have no idea how to translate those tutorials into xCode 4. I guess my question is where can I find some tutorials/books/videos on using Xcode 4 to learn application development for the iPhone/iPad.

Comment: You can also have a separate XCode 3 install just for those 'older' tutorials. When installing just choose to place it in a different folder (not /Developer).

Answer (score 1):

Apple has some good documentation on transitioning from Xcode 3 to Xcode 4, and these may help you to translate from the resources you currently have. Here are my favorites:

- [About Xcode 4](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [About the transition to Xcode 4](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Designing User Interfaces in Xcode 4](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html)

I also liked [this guide](http://pilky.me/view/15) that I found online.

Comment: Ive seen those but should I read the material for xCode 3 and then use the transition guides to bring them together? Can you download old copies of the xcode? It just is difficult to learn when everything was written for an older version of the software.

Comment: @steveied, you should be able to download Xcode 3 from [here](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=207920) but I'd stick with xcode 4 and persevere.

Comment: @Steveied: I agree with @Jonathan. You can download Xcode 3, but it makes sense to start with the latest tools. Apple's guides point out differences, so whenever you feel stuck with your references, consult these to see if the problem is a 3/4 issue. It's not a great solution, but it should get you up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two great iPhone and Objective-C development books I've worked with that use Xcode 4 for the basis of their examples.  Both of these books were released this month and contain some of the most up to date information.

[Programming in Objective-C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321711394) by Addison Wesley

[Programming iOS 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449388434) by O'Reilly Media